# need to use hadoop native

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am invoking a `mapreduce` job from my java program.
Today, when I set the `mapreduce` job's input format to :`LzoTextInputFormat`
The `mapreduce` job fails:

```
Could not load native gpl library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader.<clinit>(GPLNativeCodeLoader.java:32)
at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec.<clinit>(LzoCodec.java:67)
at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.listStatus(LzoTextInputFormat.java:58)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.getSplits(LzoTextInputFormat.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
at company.Validation.run(Validation.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at company.mapreduceTest.main(mapreduceTest.java:18)
Apr 5, 2012 4:40:29 PM com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec <clinit>
SEVERE: Cannot load native-lzo without native-hadoop
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://D-SJC-00535164:9000/local/usecases /gbase014/outbound/seed_2012-03-12_06-34-39/1_1.lzo.index, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:648)
at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoIndex.readIndex(LzoIndex.java:169)
at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.listStatus(LzoTextInputFormat.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.getSplits(LzoTextInputFormat.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
at company.Validation.run(Validation.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at company.stopTransfer.mapreduceTest.main(mapreduceTest.java:18)
Apr 5, 2012 4:40:29 PM company.Validation run
 SEVERE: LinkExtractor: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs://D-SJC-00535164:9000/local/usecases/gbase014/outbound/seed_2012-03-12_06-34-39/1_1.lzo.index, expected: file:///
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:357)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:648)
at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoIndex.readIndex(LzoIndex.java:169)
at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.listStatus(LzoTextInputFormat.java:69)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
at com.hadoop.mapreduce.LzoTextInputFormat.getSplits(LzoTextInputFormat.java:85)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
at company.Validation.run(Validation.java:99)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
at company.stopTransfer.mapreduceTest.main(mapreduceTest.java:18)
```

But in lib/native they are some files extends with a,la,so...
I tried to set them in my path environment variable, but it still doesn't work.

Could anyone please give me a suggestion!!!!

Thank you very much!

Comment: What environment are you running on? What version of hadoop? Do you have hadoop-native installed?

Comment: i am using hadoop-0.20.0 I think I have hadoop-native. I can run the mapreduce job from command line : hadoop jar validation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error relates to the actual shared library for Lzo not being present in the hadoop native library folder.

The code for `GPLNativeCodeLoader` is looking for a shared library called `gplcompression`. Java is actually looking for a file named `libgplcompression.so`. If this file doesn't exist in your `lib/native/${arch}` folder then you'll see this error.

In a terminal, navigate to your hadoop base directory and execute the following to dump the native libraries installed, and post back to your original question

```
uname -a
find lib/native
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I have libgplcompression files in the folder. But it's still not working. Because I am calling ToolRunner from java, so I run it as java application. I set conf.set("java.library.path","absolute path to native folder"), but it's still not working!

Comment: Do you have this libgplcompression.so file on every node in your cluster?

Comment: Sorry, i mean set java.library.path in System.

Comment: And i think setting `java.library.path` only works for the job client end (i'd need to dig through the source some more) but you can add shared libraries via the DistributedCache - see the Native Shared Libraries section of http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/native_libraries.html

Comment: solved! Add the path to native in java path solves th problem.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I don't have `libgplcompression.so` listed under `lib/native` How can I get this?

Comment: @narush - this was 5.5 years ago, so depends on what version of hadoop you're running now - post a new question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cloudera Hadoop, you can install lzo easily according to the following instruction:

http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/cloudera-impala/v1/v1-0-1/Installing-and-Using-Impala/ciiu_lzo.html